# Does app non-approval cause Facebook FQL queries from my URL to have a zero `share_count`, or is that my bit.ly URLs?

Tags: facebook-application, facebook-graph, bitly

I tried setting up the app (production, because we have no test server) with a test user and used him to share the content.  The content was shared on the users' wall, but when I do an `fql query` on the `link_stat` table.   I noticed that my URL has a zero `share_count`:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20url,%20normalized_url,%20share_count,%20like_count,%20comment_count,%20total_count,commentsbox_count,%20comments_fbid,%20click_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url=%27http://bit.ly/someurl/%27
```

and

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20url,%20normalized_url,%20share_count,%20like_count,%20comment_count,%20total_count,commentsbox_count,%20comments_fbid,%20click_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url=%27http://<some-site>/somepage.html%27
```

Is this because I don't have my app approved yet?  Or is it because I'm using [bit.ly](http://bit.ly/) links back to my page to track [individual Social Media campaigns](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/64985/tracking-individual-social-media-campaigns) in Universal Analytics?

I don't know if my app is in **development mode** or not, I would think so because in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ApplicationSecurity) it states: 
 
`When testing your apps, place them into Development Mode. This hides your app entirely from all users who you have not authorized in the App Dashboard to see the app, for the roles described below. Please note that when your app is in Development Mode, you cannot call any API calls on behalf of users who cannot see your app.`

Comment: As for development mode, you can check that under "status and review" for the app at https://developers.facebook.com/.   My apps say "Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?  Yes | No"